# How to transform an array of promise objects into a promise object of an array?

Tags: jquery, promise, q

Is there a way to transform an array of promise objects into a promise object of an array? I'm looking for something that behaves kind of like [`$q.all(promises)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) in AngularJS.

Here's my code:

```
var getPages = function(courses) {
  var courses_promises = courses.filter(function(item) {
    return item.courses[0].home_link;
  }).map(function(item) {
    deferred = $.Deferred();
    item["class_link"] = item.courses[0].home_link;
    item["home_link"] = item["class_link"] + "class/index";
    $.get(item.home_link)
       .then(function(response) {
        item["html"] = response;
        deferred.resolve(item);
       });
    return deferred.promise();
  });
  return $.when.apply($, courses_promises);
};
```

I want the `getPages` function to return a single promise that will be resolved with an array of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index in the promises array. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be resolved with the same rejection.

And then I would use

```
getPages.then(getEvents)
```

where `getEvents` is another function which expects an array with the elements resolved by `getPages`.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) then just do:

```
Q.all(promises)
```

That's generally a much better idea than using jQuery for your promises as Q has a much better design.  In addition, it is safe to give `Q.all` jQuery promises and it will assimilat them just fine.

If you don't want to use Q, I believe `$.when` does something similar, but it's not nearly as clean and simple.

Comment: Thanks. But how to using q on my js file？

Comment: The simplest option is to download q from https://raw.github.com/kriskowal/q/master/q.min.js and then add a reference to it via a script tag (`<script src="q.min.js"></script>`)

Comment: If you're building anything of significant complexity though, I'd recommend using http://browserify.org/ for all your development, then it works just like server side node.js and you can do:

`npm install q` to install

and

`var Q = require('q')` to use

Comment: Thanks. But I'm just writing a simple script, and I want using jquery to solve this problem. And I'm a new guy to web dev, thanks for introduce me a power for library. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

For those who don't want to pull in another library (though I can confirm Q is great, seems to be the best promises system for node), here's an implementation of `Q.all` using jQuery's `when`:

```
function all(arrayOfPromises) {
    return jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, arrayOfPromises).then(function() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    });
};
```

This has to care of two problems:

1. Rather than accepting an array, `jQuery.when` takes a variable number of arguments, so we have to call it with `apply` to give it our array of promises.
2. The combined promise is resolved with multiple arguments, instead of a single array argument, so we have to turn `arguments` into a real array (using `slice`).

Hence:

```
var getAnimal = function(animal) {
    return $.get('animals/' + animal);
};

var arrayOfPromisesToAnimals = ['frog', 'cat', 'horse'].map(getAnimal);

var promiseToArrayOfAnimals = all(arrayOfPromisesToAnimals);

promiseToArrayOfAnimals.then(function(arrayOfAnimals) {

    arrayOfAnimals.forEach(function(animal) {
        console.log(animal);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where `promises` is an array, the jQuery equivalent of `Q.all(promises)` is :

```
jQuery.when.apply(null, promises);
```

which many jQuery programmers use whilst agreeing this is clumsy. It would be better for `jQuery.when()` to accept an array.

### EDIT

Now I've seen the full `getPages` function, I can better advise on a jQuery solution :

I think it's as simple as this :

```
var getPages = function(courses) {
    var promises = courses.map(function(c) {
        if(!c.courses[0].home_link) return null;//filter action
        return $.get(c.courses[0].home_link + "class/index").done(function(response) {
            c.html = response;
        });
    }).get();//Remove jQuery wrapper to reveal an array of jqXHR promises.
    return $.when.apply($, promises);
};
```

The `$.when.apply($, promises)` line was always correct. You just need to ensure that `promises` is a genuine javascript Array, not a jQuery collection.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. I have a array of promises, and each promises resolved with a value which will be passed to then method. When I try $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(promises){console.log(promises)}), it will print out the first promise's value on the console. I want the result to be a promised array and each elements in that array is the value each promise resolved.

Comment: That's why jQuery sucks for this kind of thing, if you do `console.log(arguments)` you'll get what you want I think, because jQuery spreads the results out among the arguments of the function you pass to then.

Comment: `jQuery.when.apply(null, promises)` and `$.when.apply($, promises)` should behave identically. `$ === jQuery`, and the first parameter passed to `apply()` is arbitrary in this case.

Comment: But actually I want return a whole array, not just the a promise.

Comment: Just use Q as a dependency then, it'll make life a lot easier.

Comment: In that case, you are now asking for something different from the question.

Comment: Yeah, finally I used Q to solve the problem. Thank you, you are awesome!

Comment: awesome! I changed in this way, Thank you!